# CSS on selected checkbox

Tags: css

I have this kind of checkbox on my site atleast 4 checkbox

```
<div id="product">
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <img src="http://test.com/dev/image/cache/catalog/chains/chain_1-50x50.jpg" alt="Chain 1 +₱10.00" class="img-thumbnail"> 
        Chain 1 (+₱10.00)
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I add css that when I select the checkbox, the image will add some border and the text will be bigger

I have this code but does not work

```css
 #product :checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
} 
 #product :checked + img{
  border:1px solid red
}
```

Comment: you can move the checkbox outside <label> and use the for attribute to map the label

Comment: is there a way on css because those HTML are generated by opencart theme

Comment: The font-weight rule doesn't work, because the label is wrapping the checkbox, it's not a sibling

Comment: Oh I see Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The CSS rule:

```css
#product :checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

will match a `<label>` that is an immediate **sibling** of a `:checked` item. In your case, the label is the **parent** of the checkbox. To make the text bold, you could wrap it in a `<span>` and then use the `~` combinator to select any matching siblings:

HTML

```
<div id="product">
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <img src="http://test.com/dev/image/cache/catalog/chains/chain_1-50x50.jpg" alt="Chain 1 +₱10.00" class="img-thumbnail"> 
        <span>Chain 1 (+₱10.00)</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#product :checked ~ span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The following should work if the HTML is as you have it in the question:

```css
 #product :checked + img{
    border:1px solid red
 }
```

If not, you likely have another element between the checkbox and the image. In which case, you can use `#product :checked ~ img` as above.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work for the image border, but the text bolding cannot be done in pure CSS without modifications to your HTML. If you cannot modify the HTML, you will need to use JavaScript like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#product input").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var img = document.querySelector("#product img");
  var label = document.querySelector("#product label");

  if (this.checked) {
    img.style.border = "1px solid red";
    label.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  } else {
    img.style.border = "none";
    label.style.fontWeight = "normal";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="product">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Chain 1 +₱10.00" class="img-thumbnail"> 
        Chain 1 (+₱10.00)
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```